# Set Spinner adapter then EditText input type changed

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have set spinner to ArrayAdapter as String list.

```
                        // Creating adapter for spinner
                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this, R.layout.row_spinner, countryCodeList);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.row_spinner);

                        // attaching data adapter to spinner
                        spinnerCountryCode.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

In this set spinner adapter successfully but LoginActivity I have also other EditText control as InputType number.

My problem is after spinner adapte set click on Edittext then first open number keyboard and then after immediate open system text keyboard.

I have also set EditText input type as number

```
android:inputType="number"
```

And manifest file set windowSoftInputMode is

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: please explain your problem ans what do you want to do clearly.

Comment: @Thunder my problem is when click on EditText then open number keyboard.

Comment: Okay , so after setting android:inputType="number"  , what is the problem happening , pls explain so i can help you.

Comment: after setting android:inptType="number" then open number keyboard but actually I set spinner adapter in same activity so click on EditText number keyboard not open if I comment spinnerCountryCode.setAdapter(dataAdapter); then work properly

Comment: check my answer below and let me know if it solve your problem.

Comment: so you have a EditText (input type number) and a spinner (which has the list of items ). Soon you open the screen keyboard appears which you want to avoid since its hiding your spinner. Is this your problem statement ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something is wrong with your R.layout.row_spinner , try adding `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` in place of `R.layout.row_spinner` and run once

```
   ArrayList<String> values;

 values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("value1");
        values.add("value1");
        values.add("value1");
        values.add("value1");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for affort @Thunder but I already tried, it's not working for me.

Comment: try setting android:focusable=false in your spinner.

Comment: still not working.

my spinner row file is below :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:tag="1000"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    />`

Comment: share your full activity code and xml code so i can try at my side and help you solving your problem.

Comment: my xml code `<LinearLayout>    <Spinner 
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                            android:focusable="false"
                           android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            /> <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="number" />
                    </LinearLayout>`

Comment: private void setSinner(){
        // Creating adapter for spinner

//        countryCodeList fill with string array
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this, R.layout.row_spinner, countryCodeList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.row_spinner);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerCountryCode.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinnerCountryCode.clearFocus();
    }

Comment: i am checking in my system give me 5 mins

Comment: `        spinnerCountryCode.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) adapterView.getSelectedView();
                textView.setText(countryBeanArrayList.get(i).getCountryCode().trim());
                spinnerCountryCode.clearFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });`

Comment: check my updated answer and the screen image also , it works fine

Comment: now i think something is wrong with your R.layout.row_spinner ,  try adding  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item in place of R.layout.row_spinner and run once

Comment: thanks for your affort @Thunder, Yes problem with my `R.layout.row_spinner` file. if I changed to  `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` then working fine.

Comment: your welcome mate , please accept this answer and send me your row_Spinner  file , i will help you with that.